# dom.click() no longer firing from ExtJS 5 on IE and PhantomJS

Tags: dom, extjs, click, migration

In ExtJS 4.2, el.dom.click() triggered a click event. Moving to ExtJS 5 broke this functionality in IE 10 and PhantomJS. It is a big problem for automation testing.

Following is an example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13l3

```
Ext.require('Ext.panel.Panel');

Ext.onReady(function(){

    var p = new Ext.panel.Panel({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        margin: 15,
        bodyPadding: 5,
        title: 'Click Panel',
        listeners:{
            click: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function(){alert('clicked');}
            }
        }
    });

    p.el.dom.click()
});
```

Run the above code on chrome ExtJS 4,5,6 - you get an alert when loading.
Run the above code on IE 10 - you get an alert on ExtJS 4. No alert on 5 and 6.

Comment: Also IE11 not firing click event for ExtJS 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

Got support for this issue. It is related to changes in the event model for ExtJS 5. See following article for more details:
https://www.sencha.com/blog/delegated-events-and-gestures-in-ext-js-5/

In the click event handler 'translate: false' will solve the above problem.
Another option (global modification) is to override dom.Element:

```
Ext.define('DomOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.dom.Element'
},

function(Element) {
    var eventMap = Element.prototype.eventMap;
    eventMap.click = 'click';
    eventMap.dblclick = 'dblclick';
});
```

But the global solution may have negative effect for supporting touch.